# unable to set the timeout for socket connect() call

Tags: c, sockets, connection

I have written on client socket program in native code and using it in android application. I am facing one strange problem when making connection with server when the server is not available.

When the server is not available, client side connect() call is going for toss, its not coming out at all. I tried to search about this in internet. Some links were explaining these steps

1. setting socket as non - block mode
2. calling the connect - If connection is successful fine
3. otherwise setting the socket back to block mode.
4. setting the socket for write set and giving it to select() with required timeout.
5. If the select comes out with socket set in write set then connection successful or connection is failed.

I tried these steps, but regardless of server is running or not select() call is always comes out with timeout only. I need your help to solve this problem.

Here is the part of the code I am using

```
bool SocketConnect()
{
   ... Creating the socket ....

   int opts;
   if( (opts = fcntl(clientsocket,F_GETFL) < 0 )
   {
       return false;
   }

   // setting socket to non-block mode
   if( fcntl(clientsocket,opts | O_NONBLOCK) < 0 )
   {
      return false;
   }

   //calling connect
   int ret = connect(clientsocket,(const sockaddr*)&serveraddr,sizeof(serveraddr));
   if( ret < 0 )
   {
       if( errno != EINPROGRESS )
       {
          return false;
       }
   }

   if( ret == 0 )
   {
      //connection successful set the socket to block mode
      fcntl(clientsocket,F_SETFL,opts);
      return true;
   }

   //set the socket to block mode
   if( fcntl(clientsocket,F_SETFL,opts) < 0 )
   {
      return false;
   }

   fd_set writeset;
   FD_ZERO(&writeset);
   FD_SET(clientsocket,&writeset);

   timeval val.
   val.tv_sec = 5;
   val.tv_usec = 0;

   int sret = select(clientsocket+1,NULL,&writeset,NULL,&val);
   if( sret > 0 )
   {
      if( FD_ISSET(clientsocket,&writeset) )
      {
          fcntl(clientsocket,F_SETFL,opts);
          return true;
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

When the server is available if i use the blocked connect call ( without using any above mentioned steps ) it will hardly take 1 second to establish the connection.

When the server is available if i use the above mentioned steps to do connect then event if i give 5 seconds time connection is not getting established. event select is not waiting for 5 seconds too, immediately its coming out returned value 0.

Please review this code and let me know where exactly i am going wrong in setting the timeout for connection() call..

Any suggestions or alternative methods to achieve are appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: I've found the linux docs on connect() to be flat out wrong. You don't get a write event when something happens on a non-blocking connect(), you get a read event - and even then I seem to remember a few corner cases where a read event weren't issued. (Keep in mind though, timed out TCP SYNs can take minutes, timed out ARP requests can take quite a few seconds as well - there's many cases where the TCP/IP stack cannot give near instant feedback on connect() )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alarm to interrupt the connection. Here is example code

```
#define CONNECT_TIMEOUT 4

static void AlarmHandler(int sig)
{
sTimeout = 1; 
}
.
.
.
signal(SIGALRM, AlarmHandler); 
sTimeout = 0; 
alarm(CONNECT_TIMEOUT); 
if ( connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) ) 
{ 
if ( sTimeout ) {
NSLog(@"timeout connecting stream socket"); //If connect will remain blocked for 4 seconds after 4 seconds this condition will be triggered
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case when you are in non-blocking mode, I don't see where you are waiting for the completion of connect.

Also, I would ask if there is something else that the app should be doing before the connection is established? If so, I would consider restructuring the SocketConnect function to be in a separate thread using something like pthreads. If the behavior of your app depends solely on a client connection, I would consider switching the socket from non-blocking to blocking prior to the connect and keep the call to connect in SocketConnect.

Comment: He's calling connect() in non-blocking mode, which causes connect() to return instantly, and deferring the connection completion (or timeout) to the select() call

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.. I solved this issue other way around. Now I am using setsockopt for setting timeout for read and write operation. Now connection is coming out if the server didn't respond within the timeout... :-)